# Check value in hash ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, hash

When I inspect my variable in controller it comes to be as follows:

```
{1=>[#<SurveyAnswer id: 1, survey_subject_respondent_id: 1, survey_question_id: 1, answer_value: "2", comment_value: nil, survey_section_id: 1, survey_instrument_id: 1, survey_competency_id: 1, survey_category_id: 1, survey_id: 1, client_id: 1, client_role_id: 1, created_at: "2014-10-06 07:27:19", updated_at: "2014-10-06 07:27:19">, #<SurveyAnswer id: 2, survey_subject_respondent_id: 1, survey_question_id: 2, answer_value: "3", comment_value: nil, survey_section_id: 1, survey_instrument_id: 1, survey_competency_id: 1, survey_category_id: 1, survey_id: 1, client_id: 1, client_role_id: 1, created_at: "2014-10-06 07:27:20", updated_at: "2014-10-06 07:27:20">], 2=>[#<SurveyAnswer id: 3, survey_subject_respondent_id: 1, survey_question_id: 3, answer_value: "3", comment_value: nil, survey_section_id: 2, survey_instrument_id: 1, survey_competency_id: 1, survey_category_id: 1, survey_id: 1, client_id: 1, client_role_id: 1, created_at: "2014-10-06 07:27:20", updated_at: "2014-10-06 07:27:20">, #<SurveyAnswer id: 4, survey_subject_respondent_id: 1, survey_question_id: 4, answer_value: "1", comment_value: nil, survey_section_id: 2, survey_instrument_id: 1, survey_competency_id: 1, survey_category_id: 1, survey_id: 1, client_id: 1, client_role_id: 1, created_at: "2014-10-06 07:27:20", updated_at: "2014-10-06 07:27:20">], 3=>[#<SurveyAnswer id: 5, survey_subject_respondent_id: 1, survey_question_id: 5, answer_value: "4", comment_value: nil, survey_section_id: 3, survey_instrument_id: 1, survey_competency_id: 1, survey_category_id: 1, survey_id: 1, client_id: 1, client_role_id: 1, created_at: "2014-10-06 07:27:20", updated_at: "2014-10-06 07:27:20">, #<SurveyAnswer id: 6, survey_subject_respondent_id: 1, survey_question_id: 6, answer_value: "3", comment_value: nil, survey_section_id: 3, survey_instrument_id: 1, survey_competency_id: 1, survey_category_id: 1, survey_id: 1, client_id: 1, client_role_id: 1, created_at: "2014-10-06 07:27:20", updated_at: "2014-10-06 07:27:20">]}
```

From this I have to check if any of the survey_id is present then in the view I have to display the text "Continue" otherwise I have to display the text as "Start".

I had added a loop as follows:

```
<% @survey_answers.each do |survey_answer| %>
  <% if survey_answer.first.present? %>
    <% survey_answer[1].each do |sa| %>
      <% if sa.survey_id.present? %>
        <%= "Continue survey" %>
      <% else %>
        <%= "Start survey" %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

But with this the text is dispalyed multiple times. How can I display it only once

Comment: @survey_answers is hash and you are iterating over it, that's why for each key in @ survey_answers you see either continue survey or start survey.

Comment: @NikitaSingh Yes, that I know. Can you please suggest how can I get the proper result

Comment: @neha, I did not get your question. will you please elaborate it...

Comment: @Sanket From the above hash I need to check if any of the survey_id is present then 'Continue' text should be displayed else 'Start'

Comment: so you want to check if the first survey_answer do have a the survey_id or not, and dont want to check the rest of the array in that key ?

Comment: @NikitaSingh Want to check survey_id from whole of the hash

Comment: survey_id should not be present in any of the hash. Then only start text should be displayed on the button

Answer (score 0):

Please try just like this:

```
<% if v.values.flatten.map(&:survey_id).compact!.present? %>
  <%= "Continue survey" %>
<% else %>
  <%= "Start survey" %>
<% end %>
```